# Is it possible for a user to lose reputation by commenting?

Tags: support, comments, reputation, downvotes

If a user comments on something, for example a question or an answer to a question, is it possible that someone could down-vote the comment or do anything that would lower the commentator's reputation?

Comment: If it is spam or such, a rep penalty is possible. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

No, comments cannot be down-voted and no rep is lost or gained by commenting.

Comments may only be flagged for deletion if they contain any inappropriate content.

Reference: [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).